# type '(String) => void' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => void'

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

This is where I use the dropdown:

```
 class _JobFunctionState extends State<JobFunction> {
  static const jobList = <String>["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];
  String dropdownValue = jobList[0];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dropdown<String>(
      hint: const Text("Choose job function"),
      labelText: "Job Function",
      value: dropdownValue,
      dropdownMenuItemList: jobList
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
              (String job) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: job,
                    child: Text(job),
                  ))
          .toList(),
      onChanged: (newDropdownValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newDropdownValue;
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

Here's the full dropdown class:

```
    class Dropdown<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<T>> dropdownMenuItemList;
  final ValueChanged<T> onChanged;
  final T value;
  final bool isBorder;
  final double radius;
  final TextStyle? textStyle;
  final Color? color;
  final Widget hint;
  final String labelText;

  const Dropdown(
      {Key? key,
      required this.dropdownMenuItemList,
      required this.onChanged,
      required this.value,
      this.isBorder = true,
      this.radius = 10.0,
      this.textStyle,
      this.color,
      required this.hint,
      required this.labelText})
      : super(key: key);

  _DropdownState<T> createState() => _DropdownState();
}



 class _DropdownState<T> extends State<Dropdown> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FormField<T>(
      builder: (FormFieldState<T> state) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: DropdownButtonFormField<T>(
            isExpanded: true,
            itemHeight: 50.0,
            items: widget.dropdownMenuItemList as List<DropdownMenuItem<T>>,
            onChanged: widget.onChanged,
            value: widget.value,
            dropdownColor: Colors.white,
            iconEnabledColor: Colors.grey,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            hint: widget.hint,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and ValueChanged is:

```
typedef ValueChanged<T> = void Function(T value);
```

Dropdown is generic, I've made everything string in the jobFunction widget, and I get this error.
if I add dynamic to onChanged parameter([image]), but the type of the parameter should not be dynamic, but String. Any ideas?

adding text to fill the requirements for edit: slkdjf s;lkdjfsd jfiosdj fsdnf lksdjf klsjdfi skjldfj slkdj flksdjlkifj sf kjsdlk;fj slk;dj fisjd  fiosj f;ajof hsiod jfsajfkl sjd fk jsdlf sdlkf lksjdfoijsfoi jsdlkjf lksadj flksdjflk sjdalkf jsakj fjsaoif jseij flisd jflksajflk jasdlk

Comment: In any case, how is (String) => void not a subtype of (dynamic) => void ???

Comment: what package do you use for Dropdown?

Comment: DropdownButtonFormField from material

Comment: could you please add the full class of Dropdown?

Comment: @eamirho3ein, just added

Comment: Why add garbage text?

Comment: They asked me to add the full class. It was long, so I had to add text, to be able to submit the edited question

Comment: you are adding it incorrect. @DusanMilosevic

Comment: @eamirho3ein what am I adding incorrectly

Comment: @DusanMilosevic class dropdown is incomplete, inside the main Container there is no widget.

Comment: @eamirho3ein it must have been a copy-paste error, I corrected it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the same issue
and what did work for me was replacing :

```html
class _DropdownState<T> extends State<Dropdown>
```

by this:

```html
class _DropdownState<T> extends State<Dropdown<T>>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

Remember also to change the overrided `createState` method:

```
@override
_BasicDropdownState<T> createState() => _BasicDropdownState<T>();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Dropdown is generic, I've made everything string in the jobFunction
> widget, and I get this error.

ValueChanged should be nullable value. If you specific to a `String` , then the onchange will specific to `String?` : means String or null.
Because if there is no changes, it must be null.

how to assign the `String?` to your variable that `non-null` String is by add a condition like below.

```
 onChanged: (newDropdownValue) {
       if( newDropdownValue != null){
         setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newDropdownValue!;
        });
      }   
    },
```

if no changes happend, then you dont need to set new value to you `dropdownValue`

hope this solve your issue.

Comment: I did the change you suggested, and now I get: `type '(String?) => void' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => void'`